# Show that the set of difference quotients of a differentiable function on an interval $I$ is an interval.[MADHAVA-2020]

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function and it is defined on $I$ which is an interval.Suppose $J:=\{\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} : x<y ,x,y\in I\}$.How do I prove that $J$ must be an interval and that $f'(I)-J$ contains atmost $2$ points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $J$ is the image of a connected set under a continuous function.
- $f'(I)\subseteq \overline J$

Comment: which continuous function are you talking about?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Without Topology